# returning findOne object to template

Tags: meteor

Having troubles understanding how to return and use an object from findOne().

my code is this:

Html:

```
<head>
  <title>count</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> hello}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
  {{showcount}}
</template>
```

Js:

```
var Database = new Meteor.Collection("counters");

if(Meteor.is_client) {
  Template.hello.showcount = function () {
    var c = Database.findOne();
    return c;
  };

}

if (Meteor.is_server) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    if(Database.find().count() === 0)
    {
        Database.insert({name: "counter", value: 0});
    }
  });
}
```

Now I'm wondering if there is any way I can access the data from my object.
changing from {{showcount}} to {{showcount.name}} doesn't seem to work at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This same issue got me a few times when I started out with Meteor...

When the Meteor client connects to the server the template is being rendered before the collections have finished being synchronised. i.e. The client collection is empty at the point you are calling `findOne`.

To see this in action stick a `console.log(c)` after your `findOne` call then try reloading the page. You will see two log entries; Once on initial page load and then again when the collection has finished being synchronised.

To fix this all you need to do is update your `hello` template to handle the fact the collection might not have been synchronised.

```
{{#if showcount}}
    {{showcount.name}}
{{/if}}
```

I tested your code with the above change and it works.

Comment: This is a great little trick to know about. You just saved me at least an hour of frustrated searching!

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do this is with the #with tag.

```
<template name="hello">
{{#with showcount}}
    {{name}}
{{/with}}
</template>
```

See the documentation below for more info on the #with tag

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/spacebars/README.md